# how to test Akka Action with expectMsgClass

Tags: scala, akka-testkit

I am new to scala akka

in my test code I have this

```
  val sendEmailActor = system.actorOf(SendEmailActor.props)

  sendEmailActor ! email

  expectMsgClass(SendEmailActor.SendEmailResult.getClass)
```

but I got test fail.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: 
expected class vndirect.elasticemail.actor.SendEmailActor$SendEmailResult$, 
found class vndirect.elasticemail.actor.SendEmailActor$SendEmailResult
```

So my SendEmailActor return a `SendEmailResult` as expected. But the test unit fail. I don't know why. What is difference between `SendEmailActor$SendEmailResult$` and `SendEmailActor$SendEmailResult`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have something like

```
object SendEmailActor {
  ...
  case class SendEmailResult(some arguments)
  object SendEmailResult // may be compiler generated
}

class SendEmailActor {
  // has ... ! SendEmailResult(...) in some method
}
```

`SendEmailActor.SendEmailResult.getClass` is the class of `object SendEmailResult`. The class of `class SendEmailResult` is `classOf[SendEmailActor.SendEmailResult]`, so that's the one you should expect.

Comment: thanks for your clear explanation. I changed my code to `classOf[SendEmailActor.SendEmailResult]`, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I came to this question with a similar problem but the suggested answer didn't work. My task was to check for the arrival of a simple case class used as an Akka message.

The solution was to use:

```
expectMsgType[Message]
```

instead of expectMsgClass. (Note "Type" instead of "Class".)